# Assigned property appears as undefined

Tags: javascript, properties

I am doing ajax. At a certain point, I assign `someproperty` to a DOM object selected by id (suppose it is `12345`), and I confirm that the value has been assigned by using `alert()`:

```
window.document.getElementById('12345').someproperty = true;
alert(window.document.getElementById('12345').someproperty);
```

At this point, the alert correctly shows `true`. Then, at some point later, I invoke a javascript command that looks up the value of `someproperty` for the object:

```
alert(window.document.getElementById('12345').someproperty);
```

and this time, it shows `undefined`. Why is the value not defined?

Comment: I have a feeling that you're doing some nasty `.innerHTML` somewhere between your to lookups of `.someproperty`.

Comment: Impossible to tell from what you've shown. Can you create a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate this problem.

Comment: @user1689607 That may be the case. I modified `.innerHTML`. Does that affect the properties in some way?

Comment: @sawa: Assigning to `.innerHTML` destroys the current DOM, and replaces it with a new DOM that is obtained by parsing the HTML string you provided. So I'm guessing you're destroying an entire section, and replacing it with a nearly identical new section. This naturally wipes out the stateful information in the original DOM. You should modify the individual DOM elements that need updating instead of wiping them out entirely using `.innerHTML`.

Comment: hi sawa, ive just run this in the console, just inline, free from the possible confusion of function scopes and it appears to work fine, the alert returns the 'true' value in the dialog window however after the alert function execution the return underneath shows the value passed back as 'undefined'. This could be because the alert command is blocking, unlike the confirm() command which will return true or false depending on your dialog choice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling that you're doing some nasty `.innerHTML` somewhere between your to lookups of `.someproperty`.

Assigning to `.innerHTML` destroys the current DOM, and replaces it with a new DOM that is obtained by parsing the HTML string you provided. So I'm guessing you're destroying an entire section, and replacing it with a nearly identical new section. This naturally wipes out the stateful information in the original DOM.

You should modify the individual DOM elements that need updating instead of wiping them out entirely using `.innerHTML`.